# Qt Creator LNK2019:Unresolved external symbol using OpenCV

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I've been trying to compile a project for the past two days in `Qt` using `OpenCV` but can't figure out why it doesn't. My application has only `main.cpp`, `widget.cpp` and `widget.h`

here is my .pro file

```
  QT       += core gui opengl
  greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

  TARGET = FaceDetect
  TEMPLATE = app
  SOURCES += main.cpp\
             widget.cpp

  HEADERS  += widget.h

  FORMS    += widget.ui

  INCLUDEPATH += C:/opencv/build/include/
  LIBS += -LC:/opencv/build/x64/vc10/lib/
           -libopencv_core2410
           -libopencv_highgui2410
           -libopencv_imgproc2410
           -libopencv_features2d2410
            -libopencv_calib3d24610
```

and these are the errors I keep getting:

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::release(void)" (?release@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ)    

moc_widget.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ)

moc_widget.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ)
```

Can anyone explain why and how I an get rid of these please?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the code that's giving you the errors?

Comment: Make sure that is not one of the issues: check if you make a debug build, because OpenCV for Visual Studio has the debug libraries names ending with 'd', you can see my answer on how to link with both debug and release http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588440/include-path-for-adding-an-external-library-in-qt-creator/20589013#20589013
Also you seem to use an x64 build of OpenCV that won't work with a Qt built for 32 bit (and the official download page Qt built with VS2010 is a 32 bit version)

Comment: Make sure that `-libopencv_core2410` etc. is correct reference to the library name. What is the name of the library?

Comment: try -lopencv_xxx instead of -libopencv_xxx, etc.

Comment: also, if it's called facedetect, you will need opencv_objdetect, too.

Comment: @karlphillip using MSCV2010

Answer (score 0):

Put a slash at the end of every file in LIBS and save it.

```
LIBS += -LC:/opencv/build/x64/vc10/lib/
       -libopencv_core2410 \
       -libopencv_highgui2410 \
       -libopencv_imgproc2410 \ 
       -libopencv_features2d2410 \ 
       -libopencv_calib3d24610
```

Now right click the project folder and click "Run qmake" and then 'build' it, this will 'make' the file and consider the changes made in .pro file.