# windows – Qt create and use self-made static library

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries

There are a few questions which seem to be similar, but nothing really helps me out. I want to create a static library inside a project and use it in the same project, but linking error occurs.

A good example, which meets my conditions very well is attached to the  Qt Ticket QTBUG-45706 https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-45706. In a simple explanation, we have an app which should use some self-made libraries. Just modifiy a few things to see my problem.

app -> main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <lib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

  Lib l1;

  return a.exec();
}
```

lib.pro

```
CONFIG += staticlib
```

If you now compile the project, you will see the following error

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl Lib2::Lib2(void)" (__imp_??0Lib2@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
```

Use Qt Creator 4.0.3 based on Qt 5.6.1, qmake with mscv2013

What is needed to bring this to work?

**CLARIFY:**

The project structure is as follow:

```
subdirs_test.pro (subdir project)
\- app (app project, includes lib and lib2)
\-- app.pro
\-- main.cpp
\- lib (static library)
\-- lib.pro
\-- lib.h
\-- lib_global.h
\-- lib.cpp
\- lib2 (static library)
\-- lib2.pro
\-- lib2.h
\-- lib2_global.h
\-- lib2.cpp
```

The 'app' project should use the classes from lib and lib2, which are static libraries.

As suggested, use the "Add Library..." doesn't change a thing. In my case, this code will be generated.

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../lib/release/ -llib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../lib/debug/ -llib
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../lib/ -llib

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../lib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../lib

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$OUT_PWD/../lib/release/liblib.a
else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$OUT_PWD/../lib/debug/liblib.a
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$OUT_PWD/../lib/release/lib.lib
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$OUT_PWD/../lib/debug/lib.lib
else:unix: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$OUT_PWD/../lib/liblib.a
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. you have to set up at least 2 .pro files. One for the lib and one for the app. in the app one add the library output path to the `INCLUDES` and `LIBS` variables.
Normally you also have a 3rd subdir project to tie up all together

Comment: [DONT use the Q_DECL_IMPORT macro with static libraries](https://forum.qt.io/topic/25328/static-library/8), the macros are only used in shared windows libraries. This in an important note from one of my co-worker. Often the macro is hidden in some other global header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use QtCreators Subdirs project. Here's a detailed step by step instructions how to achieve that with QtCreator.

- Pick `Subdirs Project` from the `New Project` wizard menu.

[image: Subdirs Project]

- Add Subrojects by clicking on created Subdirs project with right
  mouse button and selecting `New Subproject...`.

[image: New Subproject]

- By following wizards you should have a GUI or console Subproject and
  a library Subproject. Then click on subproject where you want to link
  your library subproject with right mouse button and select `Add
  Library...`.

[image: Add Library]

- Select `Internal library` in the dialog and you will be prompted to
  choose library you want to add.

[image: Internal library]

- Make sure your library subproject is included before gui/console
  subproject as subdir project will fail to build.

  TEMPLATE = subdirs

  SUBDIRS += \
      LibProject \
      CoreProject

Comment: Thanks for this detailed description, this is very helpfull! Unfortunately this doesn't work, can't find depend...

But after adding `CoreProject.depends = LibProject` it works. 

The intresstig question is, why doesn't it work in my own project? I will double check everything and see if I can find any difference.

Comment: @sandkasten Have you done the last step changing `SUBDIRS` include order. Because QtCreator generates pre target dependancies `PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$OUT_PWD/../LibProject/debug/LibProject.lib` and not meeting them your build will fail.

Comment: Yep, I changed the `SUBDIRS` include order, but if I remove the depend, the build failed. But I think this is my main problem, for some reason the build order is not correct and the lib will not be build and can't be linked. But the `PRE_TARGETDEPS` is there (in the CoreProject)

Comment: Qt reported the error `:-1: error: dependent '../Lib/release/Lib.lib' does not exist.` So the project expects the Lib.lib file but it will not be build. Do know any way to force the build?

Comment: Right click on each of the subprojects and click build. Sometimes subdir project can be a little bit buggy. Have you followed my instructions and created minimal subdirs project with library and application subprojects? Did it give you the same error? [mcve]

Comment: Make also sure to rerun qmake every time you change something in a .pro file

Comment: Wont work :/ Yep, I take the time to create the minmal project (this need the extra depends for me) and every comment from me here refers to the minimal project.

Comment: Good advice, but I always delete the hole build folder to not match any problems with build artefacts.

Comment: I will accept this as answer, because it brings me on the right track and helps me best to solve my existing problem. After changing the `SUBDIRS` order and include the `*.depends =` tag in the pro file, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try doing next steps:

1. Right button on project
2. Add library
3. Choose type (external or other)
4. Set flag on static, like this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH3iF.png)

Comment: Already tried this, doesn't change a thing. An extra bunch of code is generated but linker error is still there. I can add the generated code if this hepls.

Comment: update my question with result, because its too long for comment

Comment: @sandkasten can you try make one .pro and any .pri for you libs, and in .pro write something like `include($$PWD/lib1.pri)` and write `LIBS +=` in this .pri files

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to Qt and  doesn't know what you exactly mean.. can you explane me what to do?

Comment: @sandkasten check information [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358627/qt-pro-vs-pri), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718447/adding-external-library-into-qt-creator-project), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361229/using-a-static-library-in-qt-creator) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588440/include-path-for-adding-an-external-library-in-qt-creator) :)